# strange Set<String> behaviour

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Im trying to save set of strings between launches.

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(InAppProperties.getInstance().checkedCurrencies);


PM.setStringSet("checkedCurrencies", set);
PM.commitAll();

//second way
//PM.setStringSet("checkedCurrencies", new HashSet(Arrays.asList(new String[] { "EUR", "RUB"})));
// PM.commitAll();
```

Declaration in InAppProperties:

```
public Set<String> checkedCurrencies;
```

So if i'm doing first way - it not works after relaunch app, only for using app after change settings.

If i'm doing it second way - it works fine, but i dont know why.

Can someone explain?
Debugging shows same datatypes in both cases - HashSet

Comment: Try to declare in InAppProperties checkedCurrencies like this: public Set<String> checkedCurrencies = new HashSet<String>();   maybe it will help

Comment: tested it, didn't helped